# Unity - Replacement for a null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i got this method 
[Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWCgq.png) and im calling it in one of my objects but i dont want it to drop a Pickable on death so i tried using null, it looks like this:
 Destroyed(collision, null, ScoreBonus,1);

It works fine but im getting and error that "the object i want to instantiate is null" and i need a solution to get rid of it.

I'm new to unity and programming so if it's really stupid question im sorry and thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for null:

```
if (Pickable != null)
    InstantiatePickable(Pickable)
```